# A lot of (program) entries in the Scripts drop-down in Developer Tools in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have noticed lately that in order to debug my JavaScript, any breakpoints I put in the script files are not hit in the debugger. It seems like the scripts are duplicated and listed under the name (program) [see image]. If I put the breakpoint in the (program) script, it gets hit. When I have a lot of scripts, I have to look at each (program) listing and figure out which one is the script I want to debug. Anyone know if there is a way to fix this or why this happens?

My version of Google Chrome is 18.0.1025.168 m

[image: Script Debugger Screenshot]

**UPDATED:**
I upgraded to version 19 (19.0.1084.46 m) per the advice of Paul Irish, and I still can only debug if I put my breakpoints in the (program) files:

[image: Script Debugger Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

This happens most likely because of using 'eval' or new Function([string]) - code that is not directly referenced in a file and interpreted in global context (from a string).

Update: You are using jQuery templating, that uses the Function constructor.